# trouble with geting dynamic id in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fancybox

this is the function i want to replace  quik-view2 with  my dynamic id who can i change this on onclick function

```
$("#quik-view2").fancybox({
                'width'             : '90%',
                'height'            : '90%',
                'autoScale'         : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'type'              : 'iframe'
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this

```
<input type="button" onclick="LoadFancyBox(your id here)" value="test"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadFancyBox(id)
{
$("#"+id).fancybox({
                'width'             : '90%',
                'height'            : '90%',
                'autoScale'         : false,
                'transitionIn'      : 'none',
                'transitionOut'     : 'none',
                'type'              : 'iframe'
            });
}
</script>
```